# Как увеличить производительность mysql?

Tags: mysql

Арендуем VPS на Red Hat 4.4.6-4.
Проект при пиковой нагрузке начинает довольно сильно тормозить. Медленнее всего грузятся страницы с большим кол-вом запросов к mysql. Да и вроде обычные запросы могут не слишком быстро грузится.
Изначально был дешевый тариф с 512MB, потом со временем выбрали дороже тариф, и потом еще дороже и сейчас 2048MB ОЗУ.
Только mysql занимает от 150МБ (в простое) до 190МБ.
В то время как php обычно занимает 200МБ, а в пике может и 1500МБ.

Пробовал гуглить, особо ничего не дало. Попробовал скопировать конфиг my-medium.cnf, а потом my-large.cnf в /etc/my.cnf (с перезапуском mysql-сервера), но эффекта это не дало: страницы грузятся примерно столько же времени, mysql занимает всё теже 190 МБ в пике. Сама база mysql весит 514.2 MiB.

Нормально, что mysql занимает так мало ОЗУ? Почему не видно разницы с mysql-small.cnf и mysql-large.cnf?

Comment: Так тормозит php, а не MySQL.

Comment: Некоторые запросы MySQL выполняются недостаточно быстро даже, когда сервер не нагружен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

Занимаемая память выросла в полтора раза, но и быстродействие повысилось.

Answer (score 2):

Варианты:

1. структуры таблиц: Индексы, оптимальные размеры полей и оптимальные типы данных, отказ от избыточной нормализации;
2. если в пиковые моменты есть запас по памяти хотя-бы в 100Мб (нужный размер подбирается эмпирически) - попробуйте использовать memcached или иной механизм кеширования результатов;
3. кеширование запросов в самом MySQL;
4. для временных данных используйте таблицы типа HEAP;
5. отключите ненужные файловые операции в вашем приложении, снизьте уровень логирования приложения и БД до ТОЛЬКО_КРИТИЧЕСКИЕ_ОШИБКИ;
6. подумайте об использовании mysql-proxy.

Удачи!